# Elastic Search Watcher : handle redundant docs

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, elk, elasticsearch-watcher

I have a watcher that runs every 5 sec and get records of last 6 sec. So, there are cases in which i get the docs in the hit which were also present in previous hits.
How can I resolve this redundancy?
Thank you.

Comment: Do the documents have an id?

Comment: yes @dcolazin they have id.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.